# Sugestões da IDE / como fazer?

Tags: java, regex, javafx

Estou com seguinte problema

Tenho um texto qualquer que será inserido pelo usuário e tomaremos como exemplo

**Frase inserida:** Eu gostaria de saber programar melhor #hoje.

Queria que ao fizer loop nas palavras iniciadas pelo # aparecesse um listview em baixo destas palavras ( ex: #hoje ) e que essas fossem substituidas por sugestões nesta listview ?

Como faço ? Grato desde já.

Comment: O que deve aparecer nas listviews? E substituir exatamente por qual palavra? Pode dar exemplos do resultado esperado para o exemplo que deu na pergunta?

Answer (score 2):

Pelo uso da tag [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) creio que sua dificuldade seja trocar o `#nome` da string, no seu caso creio que isto resolva:

```
foobar.replaceAll("(^|\\s)#hoje($|\\s)", "$1" + valorAtual + "$2");
```

> Nota: Eu testei `\\b` no lugar de `(^|\\s)` e `($|\\s)`, mas não sei porque não teve efeito.

Em um exemplo simples ficaria algo como:

```
final String frasePadrao = "Eu gostaria de saber programar melhor #hoje";
final String fraseRegex = "(^|\\s)#hoje($|\\s)";

listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>()
{
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String valorAntigo, String valorAtual)
    {
        minhaLabel.setText(
           frasePadrao.replaceAll(fraseRegex, "$1" + valorAtual + "$2")
        );
    }
});
```

> `minhaLabel` seria uma label aonde aparece o texto

---

### Explicando a regex

- `(^|\\s)` busca um espaço ou começo da string
- `#hoje` busca a palavra que gostaria que fosse substituida
- `($|\\s)` busca espaço ou final da string

Ou seja, dessa forma você pode escrever o `#hoje` em qualquer posição da string, evitando conflitar com outros textos que poderiam variar. Tecnicamente o `\\b` deveria resolver isso dos espaços entre a palavra, mas não sei se é um comportamento do Java, isso simplesmente não funciona:

```
 "\\b#hoje\\b"
```

Em outras linguagens não tive problema em usar o `\b`. No entanto o `(^|\\s)` e `($|\\s)` já atendem a isso

Comment: Obrigado!!!!!!!!

Comment: Por nada @Hfleury por favor, se esta resposta resolveu o seu problema poderia marcar ela como correta? Eu ficaria muito agradecido, se não souber como fazer veja esse tutorial (é rapido): https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/3635